# Magento 2 product controller override issue

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying to override product controller. Here is the code...

app/code/Test/Local/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" type="Test\Local\Controller\Catalog\Product\View" />
</config>
```

app/code/Test/Local/Controller/Product/view.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Local\Controller\Catalog\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
{    
    /**
     * Product view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        // logging to test override    
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('Controller Override Test');

        echo "In"; exit;
    }    
}
?>
```

I am not getting what is going wrong, but this is not working somehow.

Comment: have you got any error?

Comment: No there is no error.

Comment: have you ran `upgrade`  and `clean` command?

Comment: Yes already ran that commands

Comment: I ran the your code. it's working fine. re-check your module or ran the `upgrade` and `clean` commands?

Comment: You tried above code and its working for you?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine for me.

Comment: Strange same thing not working on my local server. I am not getting any error as well. Product details page is working as it was before.  When i have added exit in code.

Comment: just copy paste my code. see answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let's try this.

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'ABCCompany_BranchOne',
    __DIR__
);
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="ABCCompany_BranchOne" schema_version="1.0.0" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" type="ABCCompany\BranchOne\Controller\Index\View" />
</config>
```

**Controller/View.php**

```
<?php

namespace ABCCompany\BranchOne\Controller\Index;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
{

    /**
     * Product view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // logging to test override
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('Controller Override Test');
        echo "In"; exit;
    }
}
?>
```

after created and pasted above code, please run the below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento setup:clean
```

let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: I am getting this error. "There are no commands defined in the “setup” namespace" when trying this command "php bin/magento setup:upgrade"

Comment: where you are tried this command? specify the path. and also have you installed composer in your system?

Comment: This command working fine before adding above code. I am trying in my local server in root of my magento installation.

Comment: You have to install composer and run composer update command

Comment: @Hardik have you updated?

Answer (score 1):

Change your namespace from:

```
namespace Csoft\Local\Controller\Catalog\Product;
```

To:

```
namespace Test\Local\Controller\Catalog\Product;
```

Comment: Please check updated question...

Answer (score 0):

Your controller file path is wrong

```
app/code/Test/Local/Controller/Product/view.php
```

It should be

```
app/code/Test/Local/Controller/Catalog/Product/view.php
```

You miss catalog folder

Comment: Thanks for your ans. I have tried from this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39424354

Comment: Yes in this solution have also mistake. Becuase you have define file in di.xml is `Test\Local\Controller\Catalog\Product\View` so your controller file path same as above answer

Comment: Tried this but not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

check your file name

> app/code/Test/Local/Controller/Product/view.php

it should be **V**iew.php

Note the capital V.
as class name and file name must be same to locate the class.