# How to override Product details Page controller magento 2

Tags: overrides, controllers, magento2.3.0, product-details

> hi all, i want to override Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View.php file
>   i tried to override but it's not loading the product page.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product as ProductAction;

/**
 * View a product on storefront. Needs to be accessible by POST because of the store switching.
 */
class View extends ProductAction implements HttpGetActionInterface, HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View
     */
    protected $viewHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->viewHelper = $viewHelper;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Redirect if product failed to load
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward
     */
    protected function noProductRedirect()
    {
        $store = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('store');
        if (isset($store) && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('');
        } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            $resultForward->forward('noroute');
            return $resultForward;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Product view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // Get initial data from request
        $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
        $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $specifyOptions = $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
            $product = $this->_initProduct();

            if (!$product) {
                return $this->noProductRedirect();
            }

            if ($specifyOptions) {
                $notice = $product->getTypeInstance()->getSpecifyOptionMessage();
                $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($notice);
            }

            if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                $this->getResponse()->representJson(
                    $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode([
                        'backUrl' => $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl()
                    ])
                );
                return;
            }
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        // Prepare helper and params
        $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
        $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);

        // Render page
        try {
            $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $this->viewHelper->prepareAndRender($page, $productId, $this, $params);
            return $page;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return $this->noProductRedirect();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            $resultForward->forward('noroute');
            return $resultForward;
        }
    }
}
```

> Please check Code
>
> Vendor\Module\Controller\Product\View.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product as ProductAction;


class View extends Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View
     */
    protected $viewHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->viewHelper = $viewHelper;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Product view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Product view New action";exit;
        // Get initial data from request
        //$customCode = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('Code');


    }
}
```

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" 
            type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Product\View" />
</config>
```

> If you have any idea please guide me thanks in Advance.

Comment: Whay you have try to overide this? And which issue you are facing there?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i want to hit the product url directly and need to be redirect to our custom controller

Comment: Do you try anything? share that code and issue which you are facing into that one.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya please check my updated question.

Comment: @HiteshBalpande take a look at here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159565/magento-2-product-controller-override-issue

Comment: @jibin george thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have recently override this controller

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Rewrite\Product\View" />
</config>
```

controller file

> Vendor\Module\Controller\Rewrite\Product\View.php

```
<?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Rewrite\Product;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
    class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
    {
        /**
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
         */

        Protected $customerSession;

        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
            PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ) {
            $this->viewHelper = $viewHelper;
            $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->customerSession=$customerSession;
            parent::__construct($context, $viewHelper, $resultForwardFactory,$resultPageFactory);
        }

        protected function noProductRedirect()
        {
            $store = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('store');
            if (isset($store) && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('');
            } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
                $resultForward->forward('noroute');
                return $resultForward;
            }
        }

        public function execute()
        {
    // Do your stuff here
            try{
                    // Get initial data from request
                    $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
                    $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                    $specifyOptions = $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');

                    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
                        $product = $this->_initProduct();
                        if (!$product) {
                            return $this->noProductRedirect();
                        }
                        if ($specifyOptions) {
                            $notice = $product->getTypeInstance()->getSpecifyOptionMessage();
                            $this->messageManager->addNotice($notice);
                        }
                        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                            $this->getResponse()->representJson(
                                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode([
                                    'backUrl' => $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl()
                                ])
                            );
                            return;
                        }
                        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                        $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
                        return $resultRedirect;
                    }

                    // Prepare helper and params
                    $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                    $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
                    $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);

                    // Render page
                    try {
                        $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
                        $this->viewHelper->prepareAndRender($page, $productId, $this, $params);
                        return $page;
                    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                        return $this->noProductRedirect();
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
                        $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
                        $resultForward->forward('noroute');
                        return $resultForward;
                    }

            }catch(Exception $e){

            }
            return parent::execute();
        }
    }
```